# Nginx: Retrieve HTTP Status of a Specific Location via URI Parameter

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have a requirement where I want Nginx, upon accessing the /check location and passing a URI to it, to reach the specified location within the same configuration and return the HTTP status of that location. For example, the request would look like this: http://test.com/check?uri=main-menu, and it should return the HTTP status codes of the corresponding location in my Nginx configuration.

I've been trying various configurations without success. Can someone please provide guidance on how to achieve this with Nginx?

I tried to use proxy_pass.

location /check {
set $target_uri $arg_uri;

```
if ($target_uri) {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/$target_uri;
}
error_page 400 = @bad_request;
```

}

This is not only one config in my NGINX.